# How to load my html file with menubar for "permament" | Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Hy. I try to create app with electron, and i found a 'problem', when page changes, my custom menubar also restart. *'hide and show'* check video: https://youtu.be/vyXnfw5Cc0s. Maybe there is different way how to change pages. From preloader.html to main.html I use `window.location.href = "main.html";`

Answer (score 0):

I found way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mainPage").click(function () {
        $("#content").load("main.html");
    });
});
```